# REST API design: how to represent users joining and leaving groups?

Tags: design, rest

I'm designing a REST API in which users create groups that other users join and leave.

A user creates a group by making a request like this:

```
POST /groups

Request body:
{
  "name": "Avengers",
  "description": "Earth's mightiest heroes"
}
```

A user retrieves a group by making a request like this:

```
GET /groups/{id}

Response body:
{
  "name": "Avengers",
  "description": "Earth's mightiest heroes",
  "members": [
    {
      "user_name": "Thor",
      "user_id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how I should represent a user joining and leaving a group. I could do something like `POST /groups/{id}/join` and `POST /groups/{id}/leave`, but that doesn't feel RESTful. Can someone please recommend a RESTful way to represent these actions?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the issue is - I don't see anything which obviously violates REST principles in any way.

Comment: Fixed it: `POST /groups/{id}/restfulljoin` :)

Comment: Assuming the acction is performed by an authenticated and authorized user, then Why not _Joining a group_ by `PUT /me/groups/{gid}`   and leaving a group by `DELETE /me/groups/{gid}`. Doing this through `/groups` resource seems a management task (e.g admins removing users from groups) rather than _someone leaving or joining a group_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST does not provide an all-emcompassing scripture that answers every possible use case. There are many ways to skin this particular cat.

You could have a membership resource that describes a single user's joining of a single group. The REST implementation would then be a simple CRUD on the `/memberships` route.

But you could also define memberships as a combined reference to a group and a person, e.g. `/groups/{groupId}/members/{memberId}`, or the other way around. I often prefer implementing both and mapping them to the same backend logic.

REST is not an all-encompassing scripture. You should look at what makes the most sense for your use case and then use that.

Comment: I’ve seen the second approach referred to as a sub-resource. I think that approach makes sense here. Let’s say that I want to return the full group when someone makes a POST or DELETE request to /groups/{groupId}/members/{memberId}. Is that still considered RESTful? (Or maybe I shouldn’t worry too much based on the first part of your response :) ).

Comment: @Matt Whether you return a resource at the end of a command is something you have to decide based on what makes sense to you, not because REST tells you to or not. However, I would not return a full group after modifying a single membership (regardless of taking approach 1 or 2, as it still expresses a membership in either case). Those are two different resources and they should live on their own resource endpoints.

Comment: What about http method ? Post or Patch ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow VoiceOfUnreason's answer touches on the HTTP verbs to use - I fully agree with them on that.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please recommend a RESTful way to represent these actions?

Any of these might be reasonable:

```
POST /groups/{id}
PUT /groups/{id}
PATCH /groups/{id}
```

The target URI is the same that we use for the `GET` request, because we want general purpose HTTP caches to invalidate previously cached responses when we make a change.  See [RFC 9111, Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-invalidating-stored-respons)

---

On the web, we normally see HTML forms being used to send information to the server, so we would expect to use POST with some `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` payload, which might look like

```
POST /groups/{id}
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

action=addMember&user_name=Squirrel%20Girl
```

In other contexts, it makes sense for the client to edit a local copy of the resource, and then send the results to the server.  So you might see requests like

```
PUT /groups/{id}
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "name": "Avengers",
  "description": "Earth's mightiest heroes",
  "members": [
    {
      "user_name": "Thor",
      "user_id": 1
    },
    {
      "user_name": "Squirrel Girl",
      "user_id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

PUT requests, in effect, "make your copy of this resource look like the copy I have enclosed" -- but the server is allowed to make its own changes to its own resource.  For example, it might be that the server chooses a different user_id for the new members.

PATCH is like PUT, in the sense that we are telling the server how to change its copy to match ours; the difference being that we are sending just a representation of our changes, rather than the entire document.

```
PATCH /groups/{id}
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[
  { "op": "add", "path": "/members/1", "value": {
      "user_name": "Squirrel Girl",
      "user_id": 2
} }
]
```

Normally, in places where PATCH makes sense, you would also support PUT, and permit the client to choose whether to send the entire representation (PUT) or just the changes (PATCH).

---

The important idea here is that HTTP standardizes [retrieval and manipulation of documents](https://ttps://vimeo.com/41763224).  HTTP methods work the same way whether the document in question is a roster of the worlds mightiest heroes or a sandwich menu from the local shop.

HTTP methods, resource identifiers, fields, and so on are of the "retrieval and manipulation of documents" domain; the work of designing a good API is in designing the right documents, and linking them properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
POST /groups/{id}/members
DELETE /groups/{id}/members/{id}
```

Comment: maybe a comment to go along with the downvote?

Comment: While I think that the suggestion implied by this answer is reasonable, it would be a much better answer if it also *explains* the idea using actual words. For example, see Flater's answer that also discusses part of your idea.